# Scrolling issue in nested UITableview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm creating a layout where the data should scroll vertically and each rows data should scroll vertically. To accomplish this I have used `UITableView` as parent and inside each `UITableViewCell`, I am adding `UITablview` for vertical scroll.

The parent `UITableView` has only two section, each section has child `UITableView`. The Child tableView has more than 50 rows. I am facing scrolling issue. 
I want that the child `UITableView` scrolls only when the respective section reaches to top of the screen. Now the behaviour is it scrolls independentaly.

How we can achieve this?

Comment: Try disabling the scrolling of child tableview

Comment: if i disable the scrolling the child tableview, the content of child tableview is not fully visible. It only shows 2-3 rows of data only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom subclass of your inner UITableView and override following method based on your condition and return true/false:

```
touchesShouldBegin(_:with:in:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting following property to the main table view.

```
self.tableView!.delaysContentTouches = true
self.tableView!.canCancelContentTouches = true
```

Another option is, Use TableView inside CollectionView